# Read column values with formula Excel Data Reader not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exceldatareader

My Excelsheet looks like this:

http://cdn.imghack.se/images/cdc24215d3d5079628a58878520c3028.png

Here is the part of my method that matters:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowExcelFile(GetExcel model)
{
    DataSet result = null;
        var file = model.Files[0];
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // .xlsx
            IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(file.InputStream);

            // .xls
            //IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(file.InputStream);

            reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true; // if your first row contains column names
            result = reader.AsDataSet();
            reader.Close();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow data = result.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(data.Table.Rows[i]["Amortization"]);
        }
    return View("ShowExcelFile");
    }
```

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write gives me no output, like "Amortization" doesn't exist.

My model:

```
public class GetExcel
{
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }

    public GetExcel()
    {
        Files = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    }
}
```

My HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowExcelFile", "ShowExcel", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files, new { type = "file", name = "Files" })<br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
    }
```

But when I use this Excelsheet:

http://cdn.imghack.se/images/1fd5dab2a891c3adda8cd33114ef07c1.png

It works fine and I get all values from column "Amortization" in output. Both files are .xlsx

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT: I have found the problem (I guess). The sheet that works has values only, the other one has only formulas. Is it possible to read the value instead of the formula?